# Associating an SQLAlchemy object with an existing record (Python/Pyramid)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyramid

When attempting to add a `Widget` to the (SQLite) DB, and associate it with an already existing `User` as defined below:

```
class Widget(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'widgets'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    kind = Column(Text)
    user = Column(Text, ForeignKey('users.name'))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, unique=True)

@view_config(route_name='name', renderer='json')
def add_widget(request):
    user_name = 'foo'
    user = request.dbsession.query(User).filter_by(name=user_name).one()
    new_widget = Widget(kind='bar', user=user)
```

I receive the error `sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: 'INSERT INTO widgets (kind, user) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: ('bar', <example.models.user.User object at 0x1050bdghd>)]`

I can add the value for `user.name` directly, but this breaks the relationship. For example, `widget.user.name` would give an error like `'str' object has no attribute 'repository'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Widget` class has a `user` attribute which is of type `Text`, which is basically a string attribute on the Python side of things and is something like VARCHAR column in the database. You can not assign a User object to an attribute which expects to be a string.

It also appears that you're trying to create a foreign key relationship using the `users.name` column - this is certainly possible but is quite unusual considering you also have a surrogate primary key on your `User` model.

You need to set up a [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html) between your two ORM classes:

```
class Widget(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'widgets'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    kind = Column(Text)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('User', backref='widgets')
```

then you'll be able to do any of the following:

```
new_widget = Widget(kind='bar', user=user)
new_widget = Widget(kind='bar', user_id=user.id)
user.widgets.append(Widget(kind='bar'))
new_widget.user_id = user.id
new_widget.user = user
```

You can also set up things from the other end as @metmirr suggested, but the magic ingredient here is [sqlalchemy.orm.relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship), not the [backref](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html#relationships-backref) which you may or may not choose to have.

Answer (score 0):

The `backref` attribute will do what you need. Add a relationship to user class as follows:

```
class User(Base):
    ...
    widget = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Widget', backref='user')
```

With backref attribute sqlalchemy will add a reference to your Widget class which will point User object:

```
user = request.dbsession.query(User).filter_by(name=user_name).one()
new_widget = Widget(kind='bar', user=user)
```